# Combine numpy arrays in to pandas dataframe (but arrays are in a one strange format)

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have these three numpy arrays (they are the output from some regression predictions, but I have renamed them).

```
target = np.array([[ 2919],
   [  912],
   [ 2365],
   [11666],
   [ 1881]])

prediction = np.array([[ 4059.],
       [ 1071.],
       [ 2123.],
       [10550.],
       [ 2287.]])

abs_diff = np.array([[1140.],
       [ 159.],
       [ 242.],
       [1116.],
       [ 406.]])
```

How would I combine them in to a pandas dataframe?

I have tried a few things including this, but I can't get it to work.

```
fields = [list(target), list(prediction), list(abs_diff)]
dat = pd.DataFrame(data = fields, columns = ['target', 'prediction', 'absolute_diff'])
```

This gives me an error:

> AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) for join arrays together and pass to `Dataframe` constructor:

```
fields = np.hstack((target, prediction, abs_diff))
dat = pd.DataFrame(data = fields, columns = ['target', 'prediction', 'absolute_diff'])
print (dat)
    target  prediction  absolute_diff
0   2919.0      4059.0         1140.0
1    912.0      1071.0          159.0
2   2365.0      2123.0          242.0
3  11666.0     10550.0         1116.0
4   1881.0      2287.0          406.0
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for that.